# React 18, react-router-dom, Amplify - Blank white screen in local host

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

Whenever I do "npm start" to give me a developer preview of the application, there is only a blank white screen. This developed after I installed `react-router-dom` and tried to implement it in my code.

Below is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css"; // Ensure React UI libraries are styled correctly
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig) // Configures the Amplify libraries with the cloud backend set up via the Amplify CLI

import { render } from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
//render(<App tab="home" />, container);

const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Below is my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './routes/Home';
import NoMatch from './routes/NoMatch';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is my Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Home() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the home page!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

### I tried looking at previous forms with the same issue and tried many different solutions, but I couldn't really get it to work. Above is what I currently have.

New [Files]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlmVb.png

index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering anything into a Router. Wrap the `App` in the `Router` so it has a routing context available to it.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

// targets `<div id="root"></div>` in index.html
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router> // <-- Wrap App component
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App` doesn't need to import any router now.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './routes/Home';
import NoMatch from './routes/NoMatch';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying so fast! Your response did help me understand the code better, and it did fix the errors in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately, the screen is still white. When I check the console, I get the error "Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element". By chance, would you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Full error message - Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at createRoot (react-dom.development.js:29345:1)
    at Object.createRoot$1 [as createRoot] (react-dom.development.js:29800:1)
    at exports.createRoot (client.js:12:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:17:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1

Comment: @Xavier Well, the "default" div a React app is rendered into is *typically* given `id="root"`, but your code appears to be targeting an element with `id="app"`. Can you check your index.html file (and/or add it to your post so we can see it)? Did you also just recently upgrade to `react@18`?

Comment: Yes! this is a new computer. And I'm a bit new to web development. I don't believe I even have an index.html or at least it isn't with the other indexes, I added a photo to the post showing what I mean.

Comment: @Xavier Oh, sorry, the `index.html` file will/should be in the `"/public"` directory. It's the file that gets served up to clients and the React code gets injected into it.

Comment: ohhh ok, Index.html added

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me out. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Xavier It's the `<div id="root"></div>` div the React code should target. The code is `document.getElementById('root')`. I'll update my answer to reflect this. ***Not*** getting the React code into the `index.html` file will 100% certainly render a blank page. 

Answer (score -1):

Thank you ! i had the same problem but now it's work

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment.